# Android WebView zoom out after page is loaded

Tags: android, url, webview, load, zooming

I have an initialized WebView with the following code:

```
_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       while (view.zoomOut());
    }
_webView.loadURL("path/to/image.png");
```

But this does not work. The WebView zooms out while loading. But when it is finished, it will zoom in.

Is there any other way to zoom out completely after a page (I use the WebView to display an image) is loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this piece of code:

```
public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity 
{
     WebView wb;
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);        
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
        wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        wb.loadUrl("http://www.foofoo.com");        
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, `wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` did the trick for me :D

Comment: You're welcome. It sure does, but you might also want to include `wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)` along with it for better results. Anyway, I've included all essential settings in my code. Didn't want it to fail somewhere. :) BTW, thanks for accepting the answer :)

Comment: I do use `.setUseWideViewPort(true)` already. And now also the following ones: `.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR); .setBuiltInZoomControls(true); .setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` These should provide the best results for my purpose. Thanks again =)

Comment: If I want the page loaded fit the screen width,but after that,if user want to zoom in the content it's too small to see it clearly.How we can free the Webview to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything in `onPageFinished()` instead use `webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebviewSetting.ZoomDensity.FAR);`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

These are the two most important commands when loading images:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```